# Gather sequential data within mvc's razor pipline

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

We are still using asp.net mvc WebForms (legacy code) with a lot of our own frameworks.
one of our features is  gathering the static content on run time and creating the min and optimize versions. (we found out it was faster).

Yet Razor rendering pipeline is different then WebForms, so the content is rendered out of order.

For example  we have a view to render lets call it Home, Home has several calls to X.Css("css_x");
we gather them into a 'list' Home has partial view to render which inside also has X.Css invocation.

After Home is rendered into the output buffer stack the _Layout is rendered again with X.Css being called. assume that now we need to render all of the css files but the order is wrong.

How is it possible to synchronize view and layout with the order i need (first layout then views and partials)

Any one got an idea.

(if i am not understood please let me know and i'll try to elaborate more)

Comment: Are you rendering your CSS dynamically on each page load?

Comment: Yes, we create the groups dynamically cache them per page. we did some testing and we found that it is on the pagefaster (not for the first guy )

Comment: You realise that while an individual page may be faster, that your entire experience will be slower?

Comment: We ran full load tests, crazy monkey tests, burst mode tests -> the result are better.

Comment: So you generate a different CSS for each page right?

Comment: css groups -> one is common to all pages one is unique to the page

Comment: So you have an overhead for every single page with this extra CSS that you make the client download. If all CSS was in a single file, that file could be cached by the browser on first page and never requested again. This is why there are no CSS frameworks for doing this kind of thing. The only time you want to do "clever" things with CSS is if you need to do critical path stuff.

Comment: the client gets exactly the CSS it needs within two loads. we use caching and so on.. believe me that we've tested it enough to determine all the factors. sometimes not doing all others are doing might pay off